# lodash search with startsWith function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

i have set of error codes for which i have to display a custom message. I am trying to find the matching error using lodash startsWith function. Tried this in codepen and getting undefined. Please can you help?

```
// An array, object or any data (eg. from an ajax call)
let errorCodes = ['ErrorCode1', 'ErrorCode2', 'ErrorCode3', 'ErrorCode4', 'ErrorCodeBusiness']

let response = {

        meta:
        {
            version: "1.0",
            time: "2017-07-20 08:28 AM GMT"
        },

            errors:
            {
                errors:
                [
                    {
                        id: null,
                        code: "ErrorCodeBusiness",
                        message: "",
                        uuid: ""
                    }
                ],
                warnings: null
            }

    };

    //Find the error code that starts with given set of errors
    const hasError = _.find(response.errors.erorrs,  (error) => {
      _.some(errorCodes, (code) => _.startsWith(code,error.code))

    })

    console.log(hasError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- Spelling error: you want `response.errors.errors` (your 'r' is misplaced)
- The result of `_.some` is not returned: add `return` before it.

That will give you the result.